# Custom macro for multicolumn with & without xparse

Tags: tables, macros, multicolumn

The following example has two normal LaTeX `\newcommand` macros and two xparse `\NewDocumentCommand` for specifying multicolumn text. The only difference between each pair of commands is one has the alignment character as part of the macro and one does not.  However, the xparse version that requires the alignment character to be outside of the macro does NOT work and results in `Misplaced \omit.` error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\MulticolumnA}[3]{&\multicolumn{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\newcommand{\MulticolumnB}[3]{ \multicolumn{#1}{#2}{#3}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\MulticolumnX}{m m m}{&\multicolumn{#1}{#2}{#3}}
\NewDocumentCommand{\MulticolumnY}{m m m}{ \multicolumn{#1}{#2}{#3}}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tabular}{lllllll}
    {a} \MulticolumnA{4}{l}{A-abcdefghijkli}\\
    {a}&\MulticolumnB{4}{l}{B-abcdefghijkli}\\
    {a} \MulticolumnX{4}{l}{X-abcdefghijkli}\\
    %{a}&\MulticolumnY{4}{l}{Y-abcdefghijkli}\\
    {col1}&col2&{col3}&{col4}&{col5}\\
\end{tabular}
\]
\end{document}
```

Above compiles as is, but does not compile if the one line is uncommented.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`\NewDocumentCommand` creates a robust command, via `\protected`. The documentation about e-TeX says, on page 14, that protected macros are not expanded when looking ahead in an alignment for `\noalign` or `\omit`. So, with `\MulticolumnY` after the `&`, the search for an `\omit` ends and when TeX expands `\MulticolumnY` it finds a misplaced `\omit` (from `\multicolumn`). You have to use `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` for this.

<sub>`\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` has been added in the 2017/03/11 release of `xparse`. Previously only `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` was available.</sub>

With `\MulticolumnX` this doesn't happen, because the command is *not* expanded when TeX is looking for `\omit`; it finds `&`, so it finishes the table entry and starts a new one, but now it can see directly `\multicolumn` and is happy.