# "! Misplaced \omit" error

Tags: tables, multicolumn

The code below describes a table that goes like:

```
|_|x x|x x|

|x|x|x|x|x|

|x|x|x|x|x|
```

where

`|_|` = empty cell, `|x x|` = `multicolumn{2}`, `|x|` = cell with text in it.

```
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|}
\label{tlc}
\cline{2-5}
& \multicolumn{2}{|c}{1 Sec Trials} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{100 Sec Trials} \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Target Rate} & Mean & Std. Dev & Mean & Std. Dev \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|r|}{1Hz} & 1.07 & 1.08 & 1.22 & 0.11 \\
\multicolumn{1}{|r|}{5Hz} & 4.71 & 2.09 & 4.51 & 0.21 \\
\multicolumn{1}{|r|}{10Hz} & 10.3 & 3.28  & 10.1 & 0.32 \\
\multicolumn{1}{|r|}{100Hz} & 93.6 & 9.91 & 94.6 & 0.97 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
```

However, when I run it I get an error that reads

```
! Misplaced \omit.
\@cline #1-#2\@nil ->\omit
\@multicnt #1\advance \@multispan \m@ne \ifnum \@...
l.60 \cline{2-5}
I expect to see \omit only after tab marks or the \cr of
an alignment. Proceed, and I'll ignore this case.
```

I've Googled around and it seems that people often get errors like this when nesting `\multicolumns` inside `\multirows`, or when they put text in the cell before starting the `\multicolumn`. But that is not the case in my code.

Can anyone tell me what is going on??

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: Note for future readers: the error itself is not caused by the `\label`, **it's caused by `\cline` being not at the start of the cell** (technically "alignment entry"), but nevertheless it **does not make sense** for `\label` to be placed inside a `tabular` anyway.

Comment: Note for future readers: the error itself is not caused by the `\label`, **it's caused by `\cline` being not at the start of the cell** (technically "alignment entry"), but nevertheless it **does not make sense** for `\label` to be placed inside a `tabular` anyway. If you see the same error message your problem might be one of [tables - Custom macro for multicolumn with & without xparse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/17133) or [tables - Multicolumn error when used within a newcommand with \\@ifstar](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/67947) instead, but the fundamental cause is the same.

Answer (score 18):

You cannot place a `\label` as the first element in a cell. If you're interested in labelling the table, place the `tabular` in a `table` environment, add a `\caption` and place the `\label` *after* it:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c|}
    \cline{2-5}
    & \multicolumn{2}{|c}{1 Sec Trials} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{100 Sec Trials} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{Target Rate} & Mean & Std. Dev & Mean & Std. Dev \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{1Hz} & 1.07 & 1.08 & 1.22 & 0.11 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{5Hz} & 4.71 & 2.09 & 4.51 & 0.21 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{10Hz} & 10.3 & 3.28  & 10.1 & 0.32 \\
    \multicolumn{1}{|r|}{100Hz} & 93.6 & 9.91 & 94.6 & 0.97 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Here is a caption}\label{tlc}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Here is a [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) alternative to your `tabular`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}% http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{r*{4}{c}}
    \toprule
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{1 Sec Trials} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{100 Sec Trials} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5}
    Target Rate & Mean & Std. Dev & Mean & Std. Dev \\
    \midrule
    1Hz & 1.07 & 1.08 & 1.22 & 0.11 \\
    5Hz & 4.71 & 2.09 & 4.51 & 0.21 \\
    10Hz & 10.3 & 3.28  & 10.1 & 0.32 \\
    100Hz & 93.6 & 9.91 & 94.6 & 0.97 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Here is a caption}\label{tlc}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was using the `longtable` environment and got the `\omit` error message, too.
In my case I had the caption/label integrated also in front of the table content.
By integrating a `\\` after the label command, the error message is avoided.

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled in this problem too, and I solved it as I tried to create the MWE, so I am reporting for future references, maybe it's trivial, but sometimes you can miss it when you have big tables. I wanted to have the first row cells bold and centered, so I tried:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    \newcommand{\myh}[1]{\textbf{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}}

    \begin{tabular}{|ccccc|}
    \myh{99} & \myh{4} & \myh{3} & \myh{2} & \myh{1}\\
    \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

The solution was:

```
    \newcommand{\myh}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{#1}}
```

That is: formatting inside multicolumn and not outside.
Hope it helps.

Comment: @egreg, you're right, I left it by mistake, when I was stripping the code to the bone. I am going to edit the comment

Comment: Yes @massi, this helps! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

Ensure you haven't redefined `span`!  I had

```tex
\def\span#1{\ensuremath{\text{span}\left(#1\right)}}
```

in my preamble.  Took me ages to figure it out.

For someone who needs to know how to get back the definition of span before the error,

```latex
% store default def of span
\let\oldspan\span

% redefine span for using in the whole document
\def\span...

% before the blocks in which you need the default def of span
\let\span\oldspan

% blocks need default span

% redefine span for the whole doc
\def\span...
```