# Using \NewDocumentCommand to redefine a table rule

Tags: tables, macros, xparse, booktabs

I was trying to redefine an old command `\lightrule` with the new syntax from `xparse`.

When I try to use `\newlightrule` unexpectedly it displays `Misplaced \noalign` error.

Minimal Working Example and desired result follows.

---

[image]

---

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\newcommand{\lightrule}{
    \arrayrulecolor{black!30}%
    \midrule[\lightrulewidth]%
    \arrayrulecolor{black}%
}

\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\newlightrule}{}{
    \arrayrulecolor{black!30}%
    \midrule[\lightrulewidth]%
    \arrayrulecolor{black}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c l}
\toprule
    test & test\\
\midrule
    test & test\\
\lightrule
    test & test\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You need `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand`.

Comment: also, you do not need `xparse` unless you have an old latex release

Comment: Crosslink to related question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/681040/optional-argument-causes-misplaced-noalign/681041#681041 https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69606/250119 and a few others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `\NewExpandableDocumentCommand` to define. As David said `xparse` is not needed unless you have an old latex release.

I also suggest you to use `tabularray` to typeset your table, it's easy to use.

```latex
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}

% \newcommand{\lightrule}{
%     \arrayrulecolor{black!30}%
%     \midrule[\lightrulewidth]%
%     \arrayrulecolor{black}%
% }

% \usepackage{xparse}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\newlightrule}{}{
    \arrayrulecolor{black!30}%
    \midrule[\lightrulewidth]%
    \arrayrulecolor{black}%
}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c l}
\toprule
    test & test\\
\midrule
    test & test\\
\newlightrule
    test & test\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tblr}
{
colspec={Q[c,m]Q[l,m]},
hline{1,Z}={wd=.08em},
hline{2}={wd=.05em},
hline{3}={wd=.05em,fg=black!30},
}
test & test\\
test & test\\
test & test\\
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the prompt reply.